# Proper inclusion of quasi-analytic classes

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known that $C\{n!\}$ is a quasi-analytic class. I was asked to find a quasi-analytic class $C\{M_n\}$ such that $C\{n!\}$ is a proper subclass of $C\{M_n\}$. My though is that $C\{n!\} \subseteq C\{(2n)^n\}$ by definition. By the Denjoy-Carleman theorem, we see that $C\{(2n)^n\}$ is also quasi-analytic. However, I can't find a function $f \in C\{(2n)^n\}$ but $f \notin C\{n!\}$. Any suggestion?

Comment: why is $C\{(2n)!\}$ quasi-analytic? the ratio of two consecutive terms ($(2n-2)!/(2n)!$) is on the order of $1/n^2$ so the series converges and Denjoy Carleman says that the class is not quasi-analytic; the famous (right) bump function $f(t)=e^{-1/t^2}, t \in (0,\infty), f(t)=0, t \in (-\infty, 0]$ is for example in $C\{(n)!^{3/2}\} \subset C\{(2n)!\}$ (inclusion by Stirling) as it satisfies $|f^{(m)}(t)| \le (2\sqrt {9/8})^m (m!)^{3/2}$

Comment: @Conrad, I am sorry that I typed the question wrongly. It should be $C\{(2n)^n\}$, not $C\{(2n)!\}$.

Comment: $C\{n!\} = C\{(2n)^n\}$ since trivially $C\{(2n)^n\}=C\{(n)^n\}$ as the $2^n$ gets absorbed into the $B^n$ of the quasi-analytic defintion (more generally $C\{M_n\} =C\{a^nM_n\}$ for any $a>0$ fixed

Comment: I see. So is there a quasi-analytic class containing $C\{n!\}$ properly?

Comment: I think so - try and think of a bounded analytic function on the reals that is not extendible on any strip so it is clearly not in $C\{n!\}$ - maybe something like $\sum \frac{1}{n^n}\frac{1}{(nx)^2+1}$ to insure that the derivative of order $k$ can be bound by $CB^kk!(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n^k}{n^n})$ and the inner sum $C_k=\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n^k}{n^n}$ doesn't grow too fast in $k$ to insure the class is still quasi-analytic; if $1/n^n$ doesn;t work, something even bigger like $1/(n^{n^n})$ should work

Comment: @Conrad, I have thought your suggestion for a couple of days, but I find difficulty for the derivative of order $k$ for the function $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(nx)^2+1}$. In fact, I can't show that the bound of the derivative of order $k$ of the function is what you said. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: added a hint as an answer as it is too long for comment; hopefully, you can pick it up from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that $f_n(x)=f(nx)$ where $f=f_1$ is quasi-analytic of class $n!$ since it is bounded on the reals and analytically extendable into a strip; since $(f_n)^{(k)}(x)=n^kf^{(k)}(nx)$ one gets a bound for $g(x)=\sum a_n f_n(x), a_n >0$ of the type $|g^{(k)}(x)| \le CA^k k!\sum a_n n^k =CA^k k! C_k$ and by Denjoy Carleman one needs $\sum \frac{C_{k-1}}{kC_k} = \infty$ so one needs $C_k$ to grow not that fast, but more like $(\log k)^k$ which insures $g$ is quasi-analytic

($C_k$ can get quite big for large $k$ regardless of how small $a_n$ is, since one can fix an $N$ and pick $N^k \to \infty, k \to \infty$ much bigger than $a_N$ - also obviously $g$ is not extendable to any strip but it still bounded if $\sum a_n$ finite so $g$ is not of class $k!$)

But using the fact that now if the sum converges for all $k$ and $C_k$ is finite as it must be of course, then $a_nn^k \to 0, n \to \infty, k$  fixed, so $C_k$ is about like its largest term for about an interval of the same magnitude in $n$ around said largest term, at least if $a_n$ is fast decreasing, one actually needs that the largest term to be where $n$ is about $\log k$ (or less) so $a_n$ for example can be taken as $1/n^{n^n}$.

This ensures that for fixed $k$, $a_nn^k$ attains its plateau for $n^n$ close to $k$ and decreases very fast once $n^n$ gets much bigger than $O(k)$. With this choice fixing $N=N_k$ st $N^N$ is closest such to $k$, we get $N \log N$ about $\log k$ so the right order of magnitude we want for $C_k$ as then we can estimate $a_n=\frac{n^{N^N}}{n^{N^N}} \le N^{N^N}, n \le N$ so $a_n \le (\log k)^{k}$ for some $N=O(\log k)$ values and much lower thereafter, giving the right estimate for $C_k$ by $O(\log k)(\log k)^{k}$. Conversely similar estimates show that $C_k \ge (1+B_k)(\log k)^{k}, B_k$ asymtpotically negligible, so the ratio $C-{k-1}{C-k}$ grows like $1/\log k$ up to asymptotic dactors $1+B_k, B_k$ negligible

This last part needs some clear estimates but I think they are doable with the hint provided.